# JPanel doesn't want to focus so KeyAdapter doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

**Background**

I had a simple game. I had one `JPanel` class and there were every thing (menu, game, game end).

Then I decided, that I should make my game better and I made two panels(one for menu, and second for game lvls).

Every thing were good, but my `KeyAdapter` class doesn't work at my `JPanel`. I don't know why it doesn't want to focus.

There is what I have:

- Main class which extends `JFrame` and here I add my panels (and `KeyListener` to first panel)

  ```
  public class JavaGame2 extends JFrame {

      public JavaGame2(){
          gamePanel = new GamePanel();          
          menuPanel = new MenuPanel();
          setContentPane(menuPanel);

          menuPanel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

              @Override
              public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                      menuPanel.changeCursor();
                  }
                  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                      menuPanel.changeCursor();
                  }
                  if (menuPanel.getCursorPos()==1){
                      if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {

                          setContentPane(gamePanel);
                          //add(gamePanel);
                      }
                  }
                  else{
                      if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
                          System.exit(0);
                      }
                  }
              }

          });
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setSize(800, 600);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          setTitle("JavaGame2");
          setResizable(false);    
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          JFrame jgame = new JavaGame2();
          jgame.setVisible(true);
      }
  }
  ```
- `MenuPanel` class extends `JPanel`

  ```
  public class MenuPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

      public MenuPanel(){
          setFocusable(true);
          setBackground(Color.BLACK);
          setDoubleBuffered(true);
          setSize(800,600);
      }
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      }
  }
  ```
- And here `GamePanel` class

  ```
  public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

      public GamePanel (){
          addKeyListener(new GameAdapter());
          setFocusable(true);
          requestFocus();
          setBackground(Color.BLACK);
          setDoubleBuffered(true);
          setSize(800,600);
      }

      private class GameAdapter extends KeyAdapter{

          public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
              ship.keyReleased(e);
          }

          public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
              ship.keyPressed(e);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

It doesn't work. `GamePanel` don't want to focus, I tried to do every thing that I read. 
I think u will say that `JPanel` is not focusable component. But when there was one panel it somehow worked.

How can I fix this focus problem?
Maybe u will say that u prefer don't use `KeyAdapter`, but I think it looks pretty nice in my code.

`setFocusable()`? or `requestFocus()`? `requestFocusInWindow()`? How should I use them? Maybe I have mistake before and this is not my first problem?

Thanks in advance.

And Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, use the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it allows you to control the level of focus that a component requires before key events are triggered.

Longer answer, the active panel needs to have keyboard focus.  You can use `requestFocusInWindow`, but there is no guarantee that the component will actually receive focus.  When to call this is a tricky thing.  You could try overriding `addNotify` of the panels and calling to there, just make sure you call `super.addNotify` first, weird things happen when you don't

You will also need to consider what will happen if the component loses focus

As a side note:

- `setDoubleBuffered(true);` is irrelevant, as Swing components are double buffered by default. Generally you might disable this if you wanted to print the component. No harm in calling it though
- Calling `setSize` on your components is irrelevant, as you components will be under the control of a layout manager, which will determine the size of the component itself.  You'd be better off overriding `getPreferredSize` and returning an appropriate size for the layout manager
- Calling `setSize` on `JFrame` is also a bad idea.  Frames have borders, this means that your viewable area will be the `frame size - the frames border insets`, which will be less the 800x600 you've specified.  Better to utilise the previous comment and call `pack` on the `JFrame`, which will pack the frame around the content so that it meets the contents requirements...
- Personally, I would also localise the `KeyListener` to the actually component itself, this allows the component to act as it's own controller making it more portable...IMHO

**Updated with controller idea...**

A "really" simplified concept would be to have some kind of "controller" that the menu and game panel could communicate through, for example...

```
public interface GameController {
    public void showMenu();
    public void showGame();
}
```

You would then pass a reference of this interface to the `MenuPanel`...

```
public class MenuPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    public MenuPanel(GameController controller){
        //...
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }
```

And the `GamePanel`...

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    public GamePanel (GameController controller){
        //...
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }
```

You would, obviously, need to construct a implementation of the controller...

```
public class CardLayoutGameController implements GameController {
    public static final String GAME_PANEL = "GamePanel";
    public static final String MENU_PANEL = "MenuPanel";

    private Container container;
    private CardLayout cardLayout;

    public CardLayoutGameController(Container parent, CardLayout layout) {
        container = parent;
        cardLayout = layout;
    }

    public void showMenu() {
        cardLayout.show(container, MENU_PANEL);
    }

    public void showGame() {
        cardLayout.show(container, GAME_PANEL);
    }
}
```

You would then construct your UI around this controller, for example...

```
public class JavaGame2 extends JFrame {

    public JavaGame2(){
        CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        GameController controller = new CardLayoutGameController(getContentPane(), layout);

        gamePanel = new GamePanel(controller);          
        menuPanel = new MenuPanel(controller);

        add(gamePanel, CardLayoutGameController.GAME_PANEL);
        add(menuPanel, CardLayoutGameController.MENU_PANEL);

        controller.showMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("JavaGame2");
        setResizable(false);    
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame jgame = new JavaGame2();
                jgame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is this just an "example" to help spark the idea, haven't tested this, just hacked out here so it might blow up :P

Comment: Thanks! I already had addNotify, and i just added `requestFocusInWindow` and it works now! Thank u.

Comment: about localising `KeyListener` I don't know how I will change contentPane from there? I don't know how to interact two panels

Comment: You'd probably be able to use some kind of 3rd party controller, which had the ability to switch from the game panel to the menu panel via a simple method interface.  Equally, you could support this through the use of a `CardLayout`

Comment: I think I understand your idea, but have not yet figured out how to do it. I will read about `CardLayout`.

Comment: Greate! I will try this now. And I am sorry, but one more stupid question, why u use `Runnable`? I thought that i need to use that instead of timer (i saw it somewhere, i don't remember)

Comment: In the `main`? This is so the UI is started within the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: oh, it stucks again( at the first time everything was 'ok' but then `keyadapter` doesnt work again. and if i use `pack()` the size is small)

Comment: *"Calling setSize on your components is irrelevant, as you components will be under the control of a layout manager, which will determine the size of the component itself. You'd be better off overriding getPreferredSize and returning an appropriate size for the layout manager"* ;) - You'll want to do this for `GamePanel` and `MenuPanel`

Comment: yeh i saw that but i didn't understand how to use it) but it wasn't big problem. the problem is key adapter( i guess, now i still have to listen your short answer and use `key bindigs` ? ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54252/discussion-between-kadymov-mukhammed-and-madprogrammer).